# Asp.NET ReportViewer :: PDF Export = System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'T2Embed': Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, report-viewer2010

I am using the ReportViewer over asp.net pages on a web hosting service.

All export works okay when I test the report on my local machine and in Visual Studio.  After I FTP the web application to the remote web host the report still works but only the Excel and Word exports properly.  The export to PDF or Word generates the error

**System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'T2Embed': Access is denied**

```
[DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'T2Embed': Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))]
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.FontPackage.TTGetEmbeddingType(Win32DCSafeHandle hdc, UInt32& status) +0
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.FontPackage.CheckEmbeddingRights(Win32DCSafeHandle hdc) +21
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter.ProcessFontForFontEmbedding(PDFFont pdfFont, Dictionary`2 embeddedFonts) +462
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFWriter.EndReport() +208
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFRenderer.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, Hashtable renderProperties, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream) +757
   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RendererBase.Render(Report report, NameValueCollection reportServerParameters, NameValueCollection deviceInfo, NameValueCollection clientCapabilities, Hashtable& renderProperties, CreateAndRegisterStream createAndRegisterStream) +61

[LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.]
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings) +167
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalModeSession.RenderReport(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, NameValueCollection additionalParams, Boolean cacheSecondaryStreamsForHtml, String& mimeType, String& fileNameExtension) +193
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ExportOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection urlQuery, HttpResponse response) +154
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +240
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same issue. I was using ascii char (diamond shape) as bullets inside the report footer. I removed it and every thing worked fine...

I think during pdf export because of these ascii chars the reportviewer component was trying to embed the font into the pdf file... so it needed the t2embed.dll file. in shared hosting environment permission has to be granted to use it. I even tried to upload t2embed.dll to bin folder, it did not work either and that produced 32bit 64bit issues.. needs access to IIS to enable settings.

May be old question .. Hope it helps some one :)

Comment: almost a year now. fell into same issue and forgot about this post and i was searching for a solution, ended up reading this answer. tried to up vote. only then i came to know it was my own answer that saved my day...  : )

Answer (score 0):

Did you send also the `T2Embed.dll`?

Try to modify the permissions on `t2embed.dll` to "READ" for "Everyone".

Comment: I am using Shared Hosting